# Error: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: installation, griddb

**having issues installing Griddb on ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**

I was following the official documentation of GridDB but i have been encountered with this error, need to resolve it in order to proceed with installation.

have a look to documentation:
[GridDB documentation](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-apt/)

The commands before execution is shared with you:

```
Unpacking griddb-ce-cli (5.3.0) ...
Selecting previously unselected package griddb-meta.
Preparing to unpack .../griddb-meta_1.0_all.deb ...
Unpacking griddb-meta (1.0) ...
Setting up griddb-c-client (5.3.0) ...
Setting up griddb (5.3.0) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/gridstore.service → /lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service.
Setting up griddb-ce-cli (5.3.0) ...
Setting up griddb-meta (1.0) ...
root@DESKTOP-T16K3HM:/mnt/c/Digital/spark# sudo systemctl start gridstore
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
root@DESKTOP-T16K3HM:/mnt/c/Digital/spark# sudo systemctl start gridstore
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
root@DESKTOP-T16K3HM:/mnt/c/Digital/spark# sudo systemctl stop gridstore
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```